# Как долго занимает публикация в play market?

Tags: android, google-play

Опубликовал своё первое приложение, прошли сутки, а оно висит, как "готовится к публикации" и всё. У кого как было, нормально ли это? Чего ждать? Просто к публикации готово еще пару приложении, пока жду. И, если там ошибка, тоже не понятно, никто ничего не отправляет.

Answer (score 2):

Публикация из-за ковида и плохой модерации долгая. В среднем неделя. Но может быть и две недели.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282

Comment: Это печально(((( за ответ спасибо

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/501621)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Интересно, а что тогдая является ответом на вопрос? Человек спросил сколько занимает время, ему дали ответ. Другой вопрос, что может быть сам вопрос не совсем соответствует сайту, но это уже другая история

Comment: Last update опубликовали за 7 часов.